# How to generate a sitemap from git log?

Tags: xml, git, sitemap, git-log

I use git to store and deploy a static Web site (HTML, CSS, JavaScript, images).

Is there a simple way to extract the last modification date of all files from git log to generate an XML site map?

Comment: I reworded the question and it was answered on serverfault: https://serverfault.com/questions/401437/how-to-retrieve-the-last-modification-date-of-all-files-in-a-git-repository